# How to convert "01 January 2016" to UTC ISO format?

Tags: python, datetime, utc

So I have the following string : " 01 January 2016" to UTC ISO date format ?

I'm using arrow module and the following code, but it's full of errors, and I was thinking that may be, there was a smaller more elegent solution as python encourages elegant and easier ways to do things, anyways here's my code :

```
updateStr = " 01 January 2016" #Note the space at the beginning
dateList = updateStr.split[' ']
dateDict = {"day" : dateList[1],"month": months.index(dateList[2])+1, "year" : dateList[3]}
dateStr = str(dateDict['day']) + "-" + str(dateDict["month"]) + "-" + str(dateDict["year"])
dateISO = arrow.get(dateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Please help me I have to convert it to the UTC ISO formats, Also months is a list of months in the year .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> updateStr = " 01 January 2016"
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.strptime(updateStr, " %d %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> _.isoformat()
'2016-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Keep in mind that is a 'naive' object without a timezone. Check out [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) to deal with timezones elegantly, or just add an appropriate [utcoffset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset) to the datetime object for UTC.

Answer (score 4):

Using [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
>>> import arrow
>>> updateStr = " 01 January 2016"
>>> arrow.get(updateStr, "DD MMMM YYYY").isoformat()
'2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)'s methods to parse this date string and then reformat it to UTC format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> updateStr = " 01 January 2016" #Note the space at the beginning
>>> d = datetime.strptime(updateStr, '  %d %B %Y') # Same space here
>>> s = datetime.isoformat(d)
>>> s
'2016-01-01T00:00:00'
```